# How to use classes from main project in buildSrc

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm having a simple single project build file.
Next to that I have a custom plugin inside the buildSrc.

From my plugin (in buildSrc) I would like to use classes from main project.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to do is generate some static pages.
This generation process is bases on loading a data file in memory.
The data I want to load into domain classes part of the main project.
But these domain classes are not part of buildSrc.
It would be nice if I would be able to re-use them.

Comment: but.. why? I have a suspicion this may be a [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)? Could you please elaborate what you're eventually trying to achieve?

Comment: @RaGe I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do anything you want with gradle. However, I do not see how you can do this with out breaking the fundamental nature of gradle. By definition you main build depends on buildSrc. If you made buildSrc depend on the main build then this would be circular. However, with that said you could do something really nasty like copy a jar library into the build source using a copy task that the build task in buildSrc depends on.

This is NOT recommended.

Comment: Just as a thought experiment, you could possibly also: start plain gradle, build regular source and then use the artifacts as buildSrc for a new child gradle process. That said, I'm with you, this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Yes I'm aware main build depends on buildSrc. So probably it's better to move the the logic from the plugin to the main project (e.g. in a tools package) and then use JavaExec from the Gradle build to execute these.

Comment: That is what I would do.